# Link Excel Shapes From Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched on Google but I still cannot find a solution.
I am new to Excel VBA and I am looking for some VBA code to link Excel shapes from `sheet1` to `sheet2`.

**Example**:

I have 10 autoshape with color blue & yellow in `sheet1` and I need the entire `sheet1` linked to `sheet2`. If `sheet1` autoshape color changes to red, `sheet2` autoshape will change color accordingly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your question, shapes are "independent" objects. So you need to vinculate them. You can get the name of the shapes with the following piece of code (running from a `CommandButton1` in `Sheet1`):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Shp As Shape
i = 1
For Each Shp In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1) = i
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2) = "Sheet1"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3) = Shp.Name
    i = i + 1
Next Shp

For Each Shp In Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1) = i
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2) = "Sheet2"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3) = Shp.Name
    i = i + 1
Next Shp
End Sub
```

Once you know the shapes names, you need to vinculate them. I'm doing this using two arrays, `myarray1` and `myarray2` (in this code, vinculation is "hard-coded" in the arrays). Then the following code (running from `Command Button2`) will scan all shapes, and if shape.name is in `myarray1`, then it will set the color to the corresponding shape of `myarray2`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim myarray1 As Variant
Dim myarray2 As Variant

'First element of myarray1 will correspond to first element of myarray2, and so on
'myarray1: name of shapes of Sheet1
'myarray2: name of shapes of Sheet2
myarray1 = Array("Oval 5", "Oval 6", "Oval 7")
myarray2 = Array("Oval 4", "Rectangle 7", "Oval 8")

    For Each Shp In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If IsInArray(Shp.Name, myarray1) Then
            TheColor = Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB

              For i = LBound(myarray2) To UBound(myarray2)
                If StrComp(Shp.Name, myarray1(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes(myarray2(i)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = TheColor
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next i
        End If
    Next Shp
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Also, you may need to add error handlers.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I been tried the code, but not working in my worksheet.

Comment: From your comment its hard to say what the problem might be. Regarding the link, for security reasons I try to never click an unknown link. If link contains an excel file, I also wouldn't open it. Please explain which piece of code is "not working".

Comment: I do not know which piece of code is not working, but I find another code replace it.